# Why can I execute a command in a terminal window just fine but encounter an error in a bash script?

Tags: bash, rename, substitution

I've been organizing my music library as of late, and I'm trying to make everything "look" the same. All my songs should look like `04 John Barleycorn.m4a`, but some of them, coming from multi-disk sets, look like `2-04 John Barleycorn.m4a`. So I immediately thought, "Why not make a bash script to do all of this tedious work for me?" Little did I know, I would spend more time trying to figure out this "bug" than it would take to just do it by hand. Only one small difference: I wouldn't learn anything doing it by hand!

So here's my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

filename="/tmp/fileout.txt"

find . -name '?-*.???' > $filename

cat $filename | while read line
do
    echo ${line:1}
    newname=$(echo ${line%\/*}/${line#*-})
    echo $newname
    #mv \"$line\" \"$newname\"
done
```

It should be simple enough, right? It finds all the files with the multi-disk format, and puts them in a text file. Each line is then read back, reformated, and is "moved" to its new location/file name. (some parts are commented out since I want to make sure things "looked" good before moving files) However, when I first tried it out (after things "looked" good and removed the `#` in front of `mv`), I kept getting

```
mv: target `Barleycorn.m4a"' is not a directory
```

and I think that's because the spaces are not being escaped. I thought by putting quotes around it would solve it, but apparently not.

But I'll try to fix that later. Here's my buggy issue. I want to remove the first character (a period) in the file name (just an example...I don't really *need* to do this for any reason):

```
line="./Traffic/Smiling Phases/04 John Barleycorn.m4a"
echo ${line:1}
```

works just fine by typing that in command-line.

But in a bash script, it responds with:

```
/home/kyleowen/filerenamer.sh: 15: Bad substitution
```

I've gotten this error many times before when using `${var//foo/bar/}` and other string operations within curly braces.

Why is it doing this? Doesn't my script effectively run all operations as if they were in command-line?

I would love a working bash script, sure...but I'm mainly asking why I'm getting a `Bad substitution` error when working with string operations. Thanks!

EDIT: I found my quite embarrassing mistake...never did I mention how I was executing these scripts. I was executing them as `sh test.sh` instead of `bash test.sh`. I assumed `sh` would execute them as your user's default shell, but I guess I'm wrong (or the default shell is not bash).

Thanks for the tips on input redirection! I'll post back what I have when I get something that works.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of quoting inconsistencies:

```
while read line
do
     echo "${line:1}"
     newname="${line%\/*}/${line#*-}"
     echo "$newname"
     # mv "$line" "$newname"
done < <(find . -name '?-*.???')
```

In general advice: use input redirection instead of piping into `read`

> Reason: the while loop woulld execute in a subshell due to the pipe

Comment: Thanks, that's been taken care of in my latest script. I definitely appreciate the tips.

The errors I encountered were from executing the script as `sh test.sh` instead of `bash test.sh`. Oops...

Comment: @antiquekid3: ah, I wondered but I dismissed it because of the `#!` line. I should have mentioned it, because, indeed `sh test.sh` is a way to force the shell selection! Glad you found it!

Answer (score 2):

Try it without the backslashes in the `mv` command line?

```
mv "$line" "$newname"
```

The backslashes makes `mv` look for files with literal double quotes in the filename.

Comment: Thanks, that seemed to fix it. I would've figured I needed the literal double quotes since the file name has spaces in it, but I guess not!